# Android : Menu items can't be removed in the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, menuitem

I need to remove the inflated menu after I return to Fragment 1 from Fragment 2 after some action.

I clear the menu after I make the `popBackStack`, but nevertheless the menu item can't be deleted.

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    if (savedItemsExist())
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_saved_filters, menu);
    else
    {
        Log.i(TAG + " onCreateOptionsMenu", " going to delete");
        menu.clear();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    if (savedItemsExist())
       getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_saved_filters, menu);
    else{
        menu.clear();
    }
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that is hack solution, but issue solved by replacing the Fragment 2 by Fragment 1 instead of `popBackStack()`

Comment: this is not the solution. take a look at @ianhanniballake answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If you have menu items tied to a `Fragment`'s lifecycle, you should instead use [setHasOptionsMenu(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) on your `Fragment` and then override [onCreateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)) in the Fragment, inflating your fragment's menu.

Comment: The Menu options set by this method remains even after the fragment with `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` was removed. What do you recommend to do when the option also has to be removed when the Fragment who set it is also removed? I tried setting `setHasOptionsMenu(false)` on `onDetach()` but although the menu gets removed, it feels like a theres a delay before the option is actually remove.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones - they are removed when the Fragment is removed. File a bug if you're seeing something differently.

Comment: Does it count if the fragment is a child fragment? So basically, I have an Activity with a Parent Fragment. The child fragments of the parent fragment is the one setting the  `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` but when the parent fragment is removed, the item set by `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` of the child fragment remains.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones - if it isn't working as you'd expect it (as seems to be the case for you), then filing a bug with a sample project is the correct next step.

Comment: I'm sorry for all these questions. This will be my first time filing a bug. Where exactly do I file it?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones - that'd be in the [Fragment component of the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460964&template=1182267)

Comment: I think I found the exact same thing filed as bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36965047 and I think its been there for quite a while but I wonder why its tagged as "Won't Fix".

Comment: Ok, so just for the other people who'll find this post and have the same problem as what I asked here, the proper work around is that your parent fragment must also have `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` so that the child fragment's inflated option menu will be removed when the parent fragment is removed. The workaround is suggested here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36965047 and I've confirmed this workaround to be working before posting here.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones - the issue was originally filed against framework Fragments (which are deprecated) and against the wrong component, so it never actually got to anyone working on Support Library / AndroidX fragments. File a new bug and we'll just fix the issue.

Comment: I see! I will file the bug then. Thanks :D By the way, hope you have another talk this coming Google IO 2019 :D Looking forward to learning more from you and the Google Android Team :D (And Flutter too) :D